# How to use autowiring and package as a jar

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jar, autowired

I am trying to build a core-services jar, where I am making use of @Component, @Service and @Autowired annotations to autowire beans. 
I am packaging as a simple jar. 
How do I use the beans of this jar to autowire in another spring-boot application which uses core-services jar as a pom dependency?

Answer (score 1):

Once you add them as your pom dependencies, you can configure them so that they will get court to your @ComponentScan

So in your Final application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.dependency.first.package", "com.dependency.second.package"})
public class Application
{
```

Using above component scan, point the root packages of those jars so that ComponentScan will detect all the components and services which are in your dependency jars.