# Spring Boot Autowiring From Another Module

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to establish connection between 3 modules in my project. When I try to reach my object with @Autowired error shows up. I'll explain my scenario a little bit.

## MODULES

[image]

All of these modules have been connected inside of pom.xml. Lets talk about my problem.

## C -> ROUTE.JAVA

```
.
.
.
@Autowired
public CommuniticationRepository;

@Autowired
public Core core;
.
.
.
```

## B -> CORE

```
public class Core {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Date date;

    public Core(int id, String name, Date date) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

## ERROR

> Field communicationRepositoryin com.demo.xyz.A.RestControllers.Route required
>   a bean of type 'com.demo.xyz.A.CommunicationRepository' that could not be
>   found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type 'com.demo.xyz.A.CommunicationRepository' in
>   your configuration.

## A - > REPOSITORY.JAVA

```
@Component
@Repository
public interface CommunicationRepository extends CrudRepository<Communication, Date> {

    List<Communication> findByDate(Date date);

    void countByDate(Date date);
}
```

Comment: Make sure you are feeding required packages to `@ComponentScan`, see a relevant question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52516398)

Comment: I have already tried it. When I use @ComponentScan, it doesnt mark underlined before running statement. When I run the project, it returns an error which i wrote in the yellow box

Comment: what do you mean "it doesnt mark underlined before running statement" ? does it shows you a compile error?

Comment: Please show us your "core" class

Comment: @Damith, Intellij Idea says OK but when i run it, Spring returns with an error

Comment: @Berkin, did u find the solution? I do have the same issue. plz post the solution in case u hv been able to resolve.

Answer (score 20):

You should remove `@Component` and `@Repository` from `CommunicationRepository` if it is a spring data JPA repository.

You should define configurations in modules **A** and **B**.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages ={"com.demo.xyz.A"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.demo.xyz.A"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.demo.xyz.A"})
public class ConfigA {

}

// If you have no spring managed beans in B this is not needed
// If Core should be a spring managed bean, add @Component on top of it
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.demo.xyz.B"})
public class ConfigB {

}
```

Then, in **C**, where you bootstrap the application, you should import the configurations for module A and module B. At this point, any beans from A and B will be available for autowiring in C.

```
@Configuration
@Import(value = {ConfigA.class, ConfigB.class})
public class ConfigC {

}
```

Comment: what if the beans in another modules A and B are initialised through beans.xml files then how can we put them under @Import annotation.

Comment: This was the answer in my case.

Answer (score 8):

Basically if you want to use @Autowired annotation on top of any attribute and use it, Obviously there should be an initialized bean in the spring context to Autowire it to your usages. So here your problem is in your spring context, there is no such bean to autowire. 
So the solution is you need to have those beans inside your spring context, there are multiple ways to get this done,

The classes that you need beans auto initialized inside the spring context as @Component

Ex :

```
@Component
public class Car{
```

or you can manually have a configuration file which returns such beans

Ex :

```
@Bean
public Car setCarBean(){
    return new Car();
}
```

And this bean returning should be inside a @Configuration class.

[please refer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html)

Then if you are really sure that you have done with this, then correct @ComponentScan should work

**EDIT**

```
@SpringBootApplication 
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.demo.xyz.A", "com.demo.xyz.B"}) 
public class Application {
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but @Component annotation didnt solve my problem. Main problem is in Repository

Answer (score 1):

Try to add scanBasePackages in the Application class.
The default scan is for the package in which the Application class.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.demo.xyz")
public class Application {...}
```